# using which command in R to copy subset of an array

Tags: r

I want to use `which` in `R` to copy a segment of array. However, it seems like `which` skips the repetitive elements. Here is an example:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,2,3)
b <- c(1,2)
a <- a[which(a==b)]
a
[1] 1 2 1 2
```

I want to have an output like:

```
a
[1] 1 2 1 2 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For reference, see `help("==")`, particularly you will want to be aware of the fundamental R feature called recycling referenced in the Value section: "A logical vector indicating the result of the element by element comparison. The elements of shorter vectors are recycled as necessary."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `%in%`.  It returns a logical, `TRUE`, when the values of `a` are also in `b`.  Then if you vectorize that, the result is those values of `a` that are also in `b`.

```
> a <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,2,3)
> b <- c(1,2)
> a[a %in% b]
[1] 1 2 1 2 2
```